# Retrieve datas from Node.js server and display it on a webpage

Tags: socket.io

I'm a node.js noob and I've been stuck on this for 2 days. It seems there are basic concepts I don't seem to grasp on how node.js is working.

**What I want to do:**
Get a stream of informations from live Counter-Strike Global Offensive games and display them on a webpage.

The datas from the game are sent to localhost:3000. If I create a simple nodejs server and print the datas, it works. 
How do I use the "body" variable from the server req into socket.io to be consumed from a client POV?

nb: this code is based on the templates provided by Webstorm.

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('test2:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);
var payload = server.on('request',function (req, res){
    var body = '';
    req
        .on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('POST payload: ' + body);
            return body
        })
});

/**
 * Setup Socket.io
 */
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});

io.on('data', function(socket){
  console.log('data incoming:\n');

 // and now What? How do I listen to the datas coming from the game and not from the Express server??
  socket.emit('csgo', payload);
})

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

Comment: Well, now I managed to print again the datas from the stream while running Express & socket.io but I'm still confused as of how I can reuse it to send it to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after 2 days of struggle and misunderstanding, I figured out a working solution forking the following and updating the code to make it work: https://github.com/fassn/csgoWebPanel